# Why template recursion can't be terminate?

Tags: c++

I write a function with template:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<int N>
int fibonacci()
{
    return N <= 2 ? 1 : fibonacci<N-2>() + fibonacci<N-1>();
}
int main()
{
    cout << fibonacci<10>();
    return 0;
}
```

I think call function of fibonacci when N is 2 will end, but i get an error in clang++11:

```
fibonacci.cpp:8:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'fibonacci<-4>' requested here
fibonacci.cpp:8:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'fibonacci<-2>' requested here
fibonacci.cpp:8:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'fibonacci<0>' requested here
fibonacci.cpp:8:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'fibonacci<2>' requested here
fibonacci.cpp:8:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'fibonacci<4>' requested here
fibonacci.cpp:8:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'fibonacci<6>' requested here
fibonacci.cpp:8:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'fibonacci<8>' requested here
fibonacci.cpp:12:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'fibonacci<10>' requested here
    cout << fibonacci<10>();
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't understand the logic of your function, so always considers *both* branches to be plausible. It tries to instantiate both branches at each function and ends up in infinite recursion.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Gc1Y13WYe